# Jersey-Apache-Client4: Add Content-MD5 to requests

Tags: http-headers, jersey, jersey-client

Has anyone figured out how to add Content-MD5 to jersey-apache-client4 filters?

In the previous version this could be done using [a filter and an adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279102/content-md5-in-jerseys-client-api). This does not seem to work with client4 though, as the headers seem to be sent before the adapter starts running.

Any ideas?